# How to get a table from a .xsd file

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a xsd file named `dsTiers.xsd` which contains a datatable named `TIERS`.

I want in my code, get this table, so I try to create like this : 
`DataTable tab = new DataTable("TIERS");` but this line create a new datatable.

What can i do for get my existing table ?

Comment: `xsd` - xml schema definition, file to validate xml. So what is `dsTiers.xsd`?

Comment: It's a file which contains a graphic representation of a dataTable. I have to debug a project which I didn't participate, so I'm still learning

Comment: Please show at least part of your `xsd` file so we know what you are talking about, and assess if what you want is even possible with it. Also this may be useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/loading-dataset-schema-information-from-xml

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is known as [Strongly Typed DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/generating-strongly-typed-datasets) and thus you can access it by name like

```
dsTiers tiers = new dsTiers();  
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(  
  "SELECT * FROM dbo.Tiers;",  
  your_connection_string);  

adapter.Fill(tiers, "Tiers");
```

Access it by name saying `tiers.Tiers`